# Telling Interface Builder about custom objects. Xcode 4.0.2

Tags: ios, interface, builder

Created a custom object and am trying to connect action to button. The guide I am following states:

"To tell the interface builder about custom objects, choose the File, Read Class Files menu item (option cmd R) and select the header file containing the custom objects' interface declaration. In this case, choose the CalculatorController.h file"

Then I should be able to see the actions in the Inspector. I am not seeing anything. I do not understand the part that says "choose the File, Read Class Files menu item (option cmd R) and select the header file containing the custom objects' interface declaration." I am using Xcode 4.0.2 so the keyboard shortcut has a different function.

Any ideas so I can continue my journey into the iOS SDK?

THanks

dg

Comment: Have you created a totally new object, or subclassed another existing one?

Comment: subclassed it from NSObject. It's very simple:

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>



@interface CalController : NSObject 
    
-(void) pressButton:(UIButton *) sender;
    


@end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guide you are reading is for pre Xcode 4.0 interface builder. In 4.0+ go to the Object Library and drag in an Object. It should look like a blue cube. After that simply set the owner of that object to you class, then you should be able to connect actions from that object to your UI.

Comment: I used a gold 'Object' cube and set the "Custom Class" to the one I created and no luck.

Comment: Ok, did you set the custom class to CalculatorController.h or just CalculatorController (The latter is the correct one), also after you typed it in did you press enter? (Xcode is weird sometimes) And is your custom class a subclass of something like say NSObject? Finally, a gold Object? I don't even see one of those in my Object Library lol.

Comment: Ok, just read your latest comment, what exactly did you type in as the custom class?

Comment: There is a dropdown menu and I selected the "CalculatorController" option which is the same as the one I created obviously w/o the .h .or .m

Comment: Ok, try entering CalController instead of using the drop down menu. I say this because i noticed in your comment to Nicolas that interface declaration says CalController.

Comment: No luck. I am selecting the class I made

Comment: Haha, i just found your issue, look in your interface declaration, you declare a void method (pressButton) instead of an IBAction. A void method will not show up in IB. Also, it is usually thought to be better to declare (id)sender rather than casting it to an object in your method name.